# Is it possible to deduce statements for odd perfect numbers from the convolution sums involving divisor functions or other arithmetic functions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, congruences, perfect-numbers

Dividing and using some identities of [1] I've deduced the following facts, see also the remarks below. After these introductory paragraphs, to motivate our question, I am asking if we can deduce some useful information for odd perfect numbers $n$ from the literature evaluating convolutions sums.

**Fact.** A) If $n$ is an odd perfect number of the form $36m+9$ then 
 is satisfied the following identity $$4\sigma\left(\frac{2n}{3}\right)=3\sigma\left(\frac{2n}{9}\right)+2(n+\sigma(n)),\tag{1}$$ and additionally also the congruence $\sigma_3(n)\equiv 18\text{ mod }36$ holds. B) If our odd perfect number $n$ has the form $12m+1$ then satisfies $$3\sigma\left(\frac{n-1}{12}\right)+\sigma\left(\frac{3(n-1)}{4}\right)=4\sigma\left(\frac{\sigma(n)-2}{8}\right),\tag{2}$$
and also the congruences $\sigma_3(n)\equiv 6\text{ mod }12$ and $\sigma_5(n)\equiv 2\text{ mod }12$ hold.

**Remarks about previous facts.** My belief is that the opposite direction of $(1)$, and the other equation $(2)$ are true, but I cann't get these to prove that each equation is a characterization of an odd perfect number of the given form. I tried work invoking Euler's theorem for odd perfect numbers $n=2^{\alpha}3^{\beta}m$ such that $(2,m)=(3,m)=1$ by cases, to deduce from the statement $(1)$ a contradiction, but if my calculations are rigths it was failed: the case 1 ($\beta=2$ and $\alpha=0$) yields $\sigma(m)=\frac{18}{13}m$; the case 2 ($\beta>2$ and $\alpha=0$) will be $(3^{\beta +1}-1)\sigma(m)=4\cdot 3^\beta m$; the case 3 ($\beta=2$ and $\alpha\geq 1$) was $\sigma(m)=\frac{2^{\alpha+1}\cdot 9m}{13}$ and finally the case 4 ($\beta>2$ and $\alpha\geq 1$) yields $\sigma(m)=\frac{2^{\alpha+2}\cdot 3^{\beta}}{3^{\beta+1}-1}$. And I cann't find counterexamples, I don't find integers $n\equiv 0\text{ mod }9$ satisfying $(1)$ and I don't find any integer $n\equiv 1\text{ mod }12$ and such that $8\mid (-2+\sigma(n))$, satisfying $(2)$. (If my congruences are rights) I have not used much specific information about odd perfect numbers to deduce these congruences.

> **Question.** Is it possible to deduce statements for odd perfect numbers, under the assumption that these exist, using convolution sums involving divisor functions $\sigma_k(n)$ or other arithmetic functions? I am asking about congruences, analysis of some convolution sums for the case of a specialization related to odd perfect numbers, I say useful identities, or congruences or specializations with applications in the study of odd perfect numbers. **Many thanks.**

If you want follow up the approach in my fact for your answer it is welcome: try to calculate special equations for odd perfect numbers or to study similar congruences for different divisor functions $$\sigma_{k}(n)\equiv a\text{ mod }b.$$ It was my attempt/approach to collect information, about odd perfect numbers, extracted from convolution sums involving arithmetic functions.

I add here the references that I've used for to deduce my facts, I've used a specialization of an identity that is showed in the second paragraph of page 255 of [1], I add also the reference for the theorem due to Touchard's.

### References:

[1] James G. Huard, Zhiming M. Ou, Blair K. Spearman, and Kenneth S. Williams, *Elementary Evaluation of Certain Convolution Sums Involving Divisor Functions*,  Number Theory for the Millenium II, A K Peters (2002).

[2] J. Touchard, *On prime numbers and perfect numbers*, Scripta Math. vol **19**, pp. 35-39 (1953).